# How to place an element to be glued at the right of a div?

Tags: html

There is a `fieldset` that I want to place just after a `div`; here is what I have attempted:

```
<div id="liste_tables">
    <div id="salles"> // div I want the fieldset to be close to
        <div class="header">Salle</div>
        <div class="flex-grid">
            <?php
            $salles = Salle::lireParCritere([]);
            foreach ($salles as $key => $salle) {
            ?>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="cell">
                    <div id="tile_salle_<?php echo $key; ?>" data-pk="<?php echo $salle->salle_code; ?>" class="tile-square fg-white">
                        <div class="tile-content">
                            <div class="image-container">
                                <div class="frame"><img src="<?php echo HTTP_IMG ?>salle.jpg"/></div>
                                <div class="tile-label header fg-cyan"><?php echo $salle->salle_lib; ?></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <fieldset>
        <legend class="header">Tables</legend>
        <div id="tables"></div>
    </fieldset> 
</div>
```

At runtime the `fieldset` is at the bottom of the `div`. So how to place the `fieldset` just after the `div` with the ID "`#salles`" ?

**EDIT :** You can find the css [here](https://github.com/olton/Metro-UI-CSS/tree/master/build/css) ; the concerned css is **metro.css**.

Here is the [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pheromix/03qsqLjy/).

Comment: Did you try css `display: inline-block` on your `div` and `fieldset` ?

Comment: same result even if setting  `style="display: inline-block;"` in the div and fieldset !

Comment: Please include all relevant code in the question itself.

Comment: Could you provide a JS Fiddle? Helps us see whats wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok , I found it ; I changed the container to be a MetroUI condensed grid :

```
<div id="liste_tables" class="grid condensed">
    <div class="row cells4">
        <div class="cell"><span class="header">Salle</span></div>
        <div class="cell colspan3"><span class="header">Tables</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row cells4">
        <div class="cell">
            <div class="grid condensed">
                <?php
                $salles = Salle::lireParCritere([]);
                foreach ($salles as $key => $salle) {
                ?>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="cell">
                        <div id="tile_salle_<?php echo $key; ?>" data-pk="<?php echo $salle->salle_code; ?>" class="tile-square fg-white">
                            <div class="tile-content">
                                <div class="image-container">
                                    <div class="frame"><img src="<?php echo HTTP_IMG ?>salle.jpg"/></div>
                                    <div class="tile-label header fg-cyan"><?php echo $salle->salle_lib; ?></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cell colspan3">
            <div id="tables"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**CSS**

```
#salles {
    border: solid 1px red;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:text-top;
}
fieldset {
    border: solid 1px blue;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="liste_tables">
    <div id="salles"> // div I want the fieldset to be close to
        <div class="header">Salle</div>
        <div class="flex-grid">
            <?php
            $salles = Salle::lireParCritere([]);
            foreach ($salles as $key => $salle) {
            ?>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="cell">
                    <div id="tile_salle_<?php echo $key; ?>" data-pk="<?php echo $salle->salle_code; ?>" class="tile-square fg-white">
                        <div class="tile-content">
                            <div class="image-container">
                                <div class="frame"><img src="<?php echo HTTP_IMG ?>salle.jpg"/></div>
                                <div class="tile-label header fg-cyan"><?php echo $salle->salle_lib; ?></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <fieldset>
        <legend class="header">Tables</legend>
        <div id="tables"></div>
    </fieldset> 
</div>
```

check out the [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ronency/L9bs7nu0/)

Comment: no ! the fieldset is still at the bottom of the div !

Comment: On the JsFiddle link i provided it is not at the bottom. If you'll create a JsFiddle with your code, and your css, we can help you better